# How to navigate using path.resolve?

Tags: javascript, path, fs, ecmascript-2017

I am inside of a folder `src` and want to create files insides another folder called `dist`. Below is what I want to do from inside the `src` folder. Create a json file inside of `dist/JSON/{file goes here}`

```
main
- src
  index.js
- dist
  - JSON
    file.json
```

So my code is:

```
const file = path.resolve(__dirname, `/dist/JSON/${filename}.json`);
await fs.outputJson(file, {name: "name"})
```

This is putting the file however inside of `src/dist/JSON/${filename}.json` and I want `dist/JSON/${filename}.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to go to the parent directory before navigating, you should add `../` to your `path.resolve()` and it should fix your issue.

```
const file = path.resolve(__dirname, `../dist/JSON/${filename}.json`);
await fs.outputJson(file, {name: "name"})
```